# Access View from current/corresponding ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, xaml

Sometimes when developing a WPF application, I need to access a certain `Window` (`View`) from the corresponding `ViewModel`, to perform or fire a method like this for example:

```
//In the MainWindowViewModel
MainWindowView.Hide();
```

But that's not really easy, and even it violates MVVM because the `ViewModel` shouldn't know anything about the View, so I started doing this instead:

```
//In the MainWindowViewModel
Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
```

This becomes impractical when dealing with other Windows (Views):

```
//In the AnotherWindowView
Application.Current.Windows.OfType<AnotherWindowView>().First().Hide();
```

So I decided to make a solution, a helper class, in which, using a method, I give the `ViewModel` and I get back the corresponding View, using the `DataContext` of the View, the solution looks like this:

**The Class:**

```
public static class ViewsAccessibility
{
    public static Window GetCorresponingWindow(ViewModelBase viewModel)
    {
        var windowAccessibility = new WindowAccessibility(viewModel);
        return windowAccessibility.CorrespondanteWindow;
    }

    private class WindowAccessibility 
    {
        public Window CorrespondanteWindow { get; private set; }

        public WindowAccessibility(ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {
            var windows = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>();
            CorrespondanteWindow = (from window in windows
                                      where window.DataContext.Equals(viewModel)
                                      select window).First();
        }
    }
}
```

**The use:**

```
//In the MainWindowViewModel
ViewsAccessibility.GetCorresponingWindow(this).Hide();
```

Is this a good practice and does it violate MVVM or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options

a. Use an event Aggregator where publish the message from the viewmodel and subscribe from view. see prism documentation for event aggregators:here is sample code

> ```
>  //view will subscribe from this message 
> _aggregator.GetEvent<CloseEvent>().Subscribe(CloseAction);
>
>  private void CloseAction(string s) { //do your logic }
>  //view model will pubilsh this request 
>  _aggregator.GetEvent<CloseEvent>().Publish(output);
> ```

b. create an interface named as IView and implement it in your view , pass the instance of IView to data context of the view

> ```
> public partial class Shell : Window ,IView
> {
>     public Shell()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>         this.DataContext.View = this;
>     }
>
>     public void CloseShell()
>     {
>
>     }
> }
>
> public interface IView
> {
>     void CloseShell();
> }
> ```

by using this you have only a reference of interface will be there in viewmodel . but not the whole view itself

Comment: I used the first options already, but thx for reminding, but I didn't get clearly the second option, the DataContext should contain the ViewModel I guess, and what should the IView interface have ?

Comment: Okay so basically viewmodel will contain a property which will a reference of IView and IView is basically referring to your view so you can call the method of interface , so no direct reference of view directly.this is one of link "http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/10/01/wpf-and-inversion-of-control.aspx"

Answer (score 1):

what I mostly do when i need to fire an event is this:

I create a Boolean property in my viewmodel and bind this property to the view like this:
(Put this in the content of your element)

```
<Element.Style>
 <Style TargetType="Element">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHidden}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHidden}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</Element.Style>
```

If you want it to be animated you can set the datatrigger.enteractions with a beginstoryboard and in this item your animation.
Here are some great examples: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

Also don't forget to put RaisePropertyChanged('NameProperty') in the setter of your property else it won't be triggered when the property is changed at runtime.